# Carry on playing AVPlayer stream when view controller is popped

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, streaming, avplayer

I have a NavigationViewController which is holding a a table of Streams that could be played. When user selects one of the streams it push's the 'RadioDetailViewController' and start streaming from URL.

What I want is when I navigate back to the rootViewController(NavigationViewController) I want the AVPlayer to carry on streaming.

Anyone able to help?

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
UINavigationController *navController = [segue destinationViewController];
    RadioTableViewController *radioTableViewController = (RadioTableViewController *)([navController viewControllers][0]);
    [radioTableViewController  setRadioStreamContinue:radioStream];
}
```

Then in my rootViewController I do this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{
 [radioStreamContinue play];

[super viewDidLoad];
}
```

This doesn't do anything and the stream stops. Sorry I'm new this and would appreciate any help.

Comment: NO ONE ABLE TO HELP?

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled on this trying to look for a cleaner solution... but have you tried setting the audio player property in the app delegate and setting it with resources from the view controller? This way the player object isn't released when the view controller is deallocated.

(I wouldn't really consider this a great answer but I don't have the rep to comment yet)